# Postfix error log - Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I am getting a lot of "Network is unreachable". I did receive the email though but I am not sure why there are so many error message.

```
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/pickup[32736]: 57262A44F4: uid=0 from=<techalerts@example.com>
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/cleanup[10376]: 57262A44F4: message-id=<63e437c9.ga60Cl/a2ZozHM5O%techalerts@example.com>
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/qmgr[15976]: 57262A44F4: from=<techalerts@example.com>, size=429, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/smtp[10379]: connect to smtp.office365.com[2603:1016:401:1000::2]:587: Network is unreachable
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/smtp[10379]: connect to smtp.office365.com[2603:1016:0:2f::2]:587: Network is unreachable
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/smtp[10379]: connect to smtp.office365.com[2603:1016:401:1052::2]:587: Network is unreachable
Feb  9 11:01:13 nagios postfix/smtp[10379]: connect to smtp.office365.com[2603:1016:401:2002::2]:587: Network is unreachable
Feb  9 11:01:14 nagios postfix/smtp[10379]: 57262A44F4: to=<slee@example.com>, relay=smtp.office365.com[52.98.0.162]:587, delay=1, delays=0.04/0/0.84/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK <63e437c9.ga60Cl/a2ZozHM5O%techalerts@example.com> [Hostname=ME3P282MB1347.AUSP282.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM])
Feb  9 11:01:14 nagios postfix/qmgr[15976]: 57262A44F4: removed
```

Comment: looks like it's trying to use several IPv6 addresses that are failing and the IPv4 one succesds

Comment: If you want to get rid of them, and be future proof, get your ISP to give you some IPv6 address space.